# R dplyr: Creating groups from two identifiers ignoring permutations

Tags: r, group-by, tidyverse, dplyr

In the data below, each row includes a first entity ("Country1") and a second entity ("Country2"). I would like to have a variable that groups rows with (Country1,Country2) = (Country1,Country2) or (Country1,Country2) = (Country2,Country1), i.e., common elements but ignoring permutations.

Please comment on the script below, which appears to work but does things I do not understand with by_row().

```
library(tidyverse)
pairs0  <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
Country1         Country2
A                B
B                A
A                C
")

## What I want to have: 
## Country1        Country2        pairID
## A               B               1
## B               A               1
## A               C               2

pairs1  <- by_row(pairs0,.collate="cols",
                  ..f=function(this_row) {
                      this_row[1,c("Country1","Country2")] %>% unlist %>% sort %>% paste
                  }
                  )

pairs2  <- mutate(pairs1,pairID = group_indices(pairs1,.out1,.out2))
```

Comment: Was my answer helpful to you. Please consider accepting it (check mark to the left of my answer)

Answer (score 0):

#### Explanation

```
pairs1  <- by_row(pairs0,.collate="cols",
                  ..f=function(this_row) {
                      this_row[1,c("Country1","Country2")] %>% unlist %>% sort %>% paste
                  }
                  )
```

`by_row` - perform rowwise operation  (on `this_row`)
`pairs0` - data frame to operate on
`..f=function(this_row) {` - this is the operation per `this_row`
`this_row[1,c("Country1","Country2")]` - single row of `pairs0`
`unlist` - convert single-row data frame to vector
`sort` - sort elements of vector alphabetically
`paste` - collapse vector into single string

In the end, for each row, you get something like (i.e. a string)

```
"A B"
```

#### Finish explanation

The following will add an ID number per unique group

```
pairs2  <- mutate(pairs1,pairID = group_indices(pairs1,.out1,.out2))
```

`mutate` - change the following
`pairs1` - data frame to operate on
`pairID` - column to operate on
`group_indices` - unique group ID